# Не могу придумать алгоритм для задачки

Tags: python, олимпиада

Условие: Мистер Твистер, банкир и финансист, имеет доступ к секретным материалам - курс местной денежной валюты на N дней вперёд. Как человек, везде старающийся найти выгоду, мистер Твистер поставил перед собой задачу - необходимо выбрать день, когда нужно купить эту самую валюту и когда её нужно продать, чтобы получить максимальную прибыль.

Формат ввода:
В первой строке вводится число N — количество дней, на которые известен курс валюты.
Во второй строке находится N чисел — стоимость валюты в рублях в соответствующий день.

Формат вывода:
Требуется вывести два числа — день, когда нужно купить валюту и день, когда нужно её продать, чтобы получить максимальную прибыль. Причем если способов выбрать эту пару дней несколько, то нужно выбрать тот, при котором мистер Твистер сможет сбыть валюту с рук. Если же и таких пар несколько, то нужно учесть тот же принцип - чем раньше, тем лучше. Если же в эти  дней покупать и продавать валюту будет невыгодно или бесполезно, то выведите -1.

Пример:
Ввод:
5
1 2 1 5 3
Вывод:
3 4

### Ввод:
3
200 100 50
Вывод:

Потуги моих рассуждений: я осознал лишь, что если на всём промежутке следующее число меньше предыдущего, то акции падают и нужно выводить -1. (0 добавил для того, чтобы избежать index out of range)

```
n = int(input())
term = list(map(int, input().split()))
term.append(0)
if not any(term[i] < term[i + 1] for i in range(n)):
    print(-1)
```

Дальше просто впадаю в ступор. Задача кажется знакомой, возможно, её условие популярно на олимпиадах. Однако, какой алгоритм? Если идти по всему списку и итератором отслеживать, когда следующее число меньше, а когда больше предыдущего, то это долго, затратно по памяти, да и не факт, что логика сработает. Был вариант искать индексы вхождений максимального и минимального числа, чтобы сравнивать их позиции, но если максимум стоит перед минимумом, то что дальше? Если кто-то сталкивался с аналогией, можете объяснить принцип, пожалуйста?

Comment: Тупой алгоритм в лоб: для каждой пары дней `i` и `j` (`i<j`) ищем сколько заработаем, если купить в день `i` и продать в `j`. Выбираем пару, где заработаем максимум.

Comment: Заголовок исправьте на имеющий отношение к проблеме.

Comment: В задаче нигде не упомянуто, что покупать надо до продажи. Это подразумевается или нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В каждый день проверяем, не будет ли разница текущей цены с минимумом до сегодняшнего дня лучше, чем имеющаяся. И обновляем минимум.

```
for x in term:
    bestprofit = max(bestprofit, x - minsofar)
    minsofar = min(minsofar, x)
```